# Rail 3: instance variable not available after redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I've a got a form wizard of sorts in Rails 3. Basically, I create a hotel object and then when all of that is complete I want to create a location object for that hotel. My controller code for creating the hotel looks like this:

```
  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.new(params[:hotel])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @hotel.save
        @location = Location.new
        format.html { redirect_to '/set_location'}
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in the '/set_location' page I have a form which sets the location. However, I'm getting an `'undefined method model_name for NilClass:Class'` error on the html.erb for the @location instance variable.

This is really strange as when I use render '/set_location' instead of redirect_to then it works fine. However, I want to use the redirect_to method in order to prevent duplicate record submission.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: what's a duplicate error submission? redirect_to redirects you to another controller action, if you don't have an instance variable set there, it will fail.

Comment: Its a duplicate _record_ submission - basically duplicate data being in the database. Does that mean that the instance variables I had in one controller action are lost once I hit another? Is there any way to pass variables between these actions? Put it in the session maybe? Bad practice no?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HTTP is stateless by design. If you want to share the state between requests (redirect leads to another request) you should use the `session` hash. Like this:

```
session[:hotel_id] = @hotel.id
```

And then you retrieve your `Hotel` in the `/set_location` this way:

```
Hotel.find(session[:hotel_id])
```

Comment: It won't help. Variables can't be passed between requests. I think the author got the idea: to use sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is:

1. Identify which controller and action responds to the "/set_location" request.
2. There you will see that you are missing this line `@location = Location.new`. You need to create it there.

Instance variables in Rails are often used to pass information between your controller and your view, and that is why when doing **render**, you don't get that error. Rails views know about instance variables from controllers.

However, you are doing a redirect, and therefore you are calling another controller which has no idea what `@location` is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Nobita's response here is the most comprehensive one and answers the OP exact question to the point. Please vote up (@Ger).

In jdoe's answer, I would anticipate or would like to see more explanation around his/her (jdoe's) use of "request" in his explanations, as "request" can be interpreted as a request for a view (or template) in other frameworks, so this statement might be a bit misleading to a new Rails developer (myself included) when read in terms of Rails:

> "Variables can't be passed between requests. I think the author got
>   the idea: to use sessions."

In a sense, variables can indeed be passed when you request a view/template from controller with "render". So if your controller method renders a view, that view would have knowledge of the `@variable` which you have defined in that controller.

Additionally, using sessions is actually not the only way to pass a variable between requests. You can modify your redirected to route to catch a variable:

Consider (in routes.rb file):

```
match 'surveys/result(/:id)' => "surveys#result", via: [:get], as: 'surveys_result'
```

Now, in the "surveys" controller "result" action method you will have an `:id` parameter. You would call it as `params[:id]`, for example to find an object in your database with this id. I believe, there is also a way to hide the `:id` from the URI/URL, in case you do not wish the user to see it there.

@shime: In reference to your question of "duplicate entry", I believe the OP was referring to rendering a view on a POST request. Imagine if a POST was successful, then you might submit a duplicate entry to the database on each refresh of the page after you have already submitted that form (re-direct method takes care of that this does not happen, and is thus the standard way to route from your POST requests) and this paragraph I found has one of the clearest explanations of what happens on both implementations:

https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155#redirect