# What's the best way to deliver a group of objects from one action to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an action `index`. And I have a `print` action.

I would like to take `@objects`, and pass them all to `print` from `index`.

I was thinking of doing this in a link :

```
= link_to 'Print', print_path(@objects)
```

But as you might imagine, that because an gigantic link, and with some tomfoolery, I get this `ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ffc3a5f8000` getting passed.

What would be the best way to pass my `@objects` variable to this secondary action ?

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104652/rail-3-instance-variable-not-available-after-redirection/10104776#10104776

Comment: That just changed my life. Thanks so much jdoe.

Comment: Then upvote that answer and we are even! )))

Comment: The link I gave points to my answer ;)

Comment: how about serialize it and save to /tmp?

Comment: How do you plan to associate your savings with, say, my browser session?

Comment: I hope the author understands that he should pass not objects but references to them. More to read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session

Comment: Yah I'm just sending a map of ID's.

Comment: @Trip: since your question was answered in a comment and your question is not exactly the same as the one linked, it would be great for you to post an answer to your own question that shows your implementation. This way the question can be marked as answered and future readers can see both what was linked that helped you solve your problem and how you actually did it. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

So super special thanks to jdoe, I was able to figure this out by the zen understanding that Rails is stateless.

Therefore, I instantiated my variable in the controller as

```
def index
  session[:objects] = @objects.map(&:id)
end
```

Instead of making it equal to the objects. I just mapped the ID's.

This session variable is now accessible indefinately throughout the site.

Then in my other action I call them like so :

```
def print
    @objects = []
    session[:objects].each{|object|@objects << Object.find(object)}
end
```