# Instance Variable string collection lost after render => 'new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, simple-form, instance-variables

When I get an error creating a quote, it renders the same page it was just on and displays the errors. Unfortunately two inputs are drop down menus of strings, and they disappear when the refresh happens.

I've looked at [Rail 3: instance variable not available after redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104652/rail-3-instance-variable-not-available-after-redirection) which talks about sessions, which looks like it could be the right way to go but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

quotes controller

```
def new
    @quote = Quote.new
    @quote.items.build
    @types = ["T-Shirt", "Hoodie", "Sweatpants"]
    @colors = ["White", "Black", "Red", "Blue", "Green"]
end

def create
@quote = Quote.new(params[:quote])
  respond_to do |format|

  if @quote.save

    format.html { redirect_to root_url }
    flash[:success] = "Your quote is being approved. You will recieve an email shortly!"
    format.json { render json: @quote, status: :created, location: @quote }
  else
    format.html { render :action => 'new' }
    format.json { render :json => @quote.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entry }
    flash[:error] = "Quote failed to create! Try again!"
  end
 end
end
```

form partial

```
<!-- item form -->
<%= f.input :make, collection: @types, label: 'Thread Type' %>
<%= f.input :amount, label: 'How Many' %>
<%= f.input :color, collection: @colors %>
<!-- nested form for creating a design of an item -->
<%= f.simple_fields_for :designs, :html => { :multipart => true } do |designform| %>
    <%= render "customdesign", g: designform %>
  <% end %>
<!-- add/remove another design -->  
<%= f.link_to_add "Add Design", :designs %>
<%= f.input :note, :input_html => { :cols => 50, :rows => 3 }, label: 'Special Notes or Requests' %>
<%= f.link_to_remove "Remove" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@colors` and `@types` are only set in the `new` action, and not the `create` action. Rendering a template does not automatically call the action method in the controller; it goes straight to the view.

A possible solution is to define helper methods for these lists:

```
# app/helpers/quote_helper.rb
module QuoteHelper
  def possible_types
    ["T-Shirt", "Hoodie", "Sweatpants"]
  end
end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= f.input :make, collection: possible_types, label: 'Thread Type' %>
```

Comment: I ended up converting them both to integers, and using select( :make {"T-Shirt" => 1 }) etc for the dropdowns, and a model method to show them it as T-Shirt not "1" on a different page. I'm not sure if this is the best solution but for now it's working, but I'll definitely give yours a try too as it seems easier.